# commands to predict the language with fastText in Linux

Tags: deep-learning, fasttext

For language identification, I am using the following tutorial :

[Fasttext language detection tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/blog/2017/10/02/blog-post.html)

After executing the command as in tutorial:
./fasttext test langdetect.bin valid.txt

I have the following the output:
N 10000
P@1 0.967
R@1 0.967

after this, which commands will predict the language? how to enter the text in other languages?

I am very new to this language detection. I could find ample tutorials for python prediction but not in linux command line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language detection is a particular case of text classification using supervised models ([here you can find the tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html)).

According to the tutorial, you can predict on new examples, by typing:

`./fasttext predict-prob langdetect.bin - -1 0.5`

*(we want as many prediction as possible (argument -1) and we want only labels with probability higher or equal to 0.5)*

and then typing the sentence.

If you have a txt file with sentences to be classified, you can type:

```
$ ./fasttext predict-prob langdetect.bin test.txt k
```

*where k is the number of classes to show.*

This [cheatsheet](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/cheatsheet.html) may also be useful.